# how to pass apdu command to command apdu function

Tags: java, javacard

Hi am new to java card I have following data

```
CLA '00'
INS 'A2' nb not real value
P1  '00'
P2  '00'
LC  '08'
Data In 'EF08'
Le   '0D'
```

How can I write above instructions into bytes and send to this function? I need to get 9000 as success response and Data out.

```
 ResponseAPDU respApdu = channel.transmit(
                                 new CommandAPDU(cmd));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that:

**Case 1:** (Not encouraged)

```
int cla = 0x00;
int ins = 0xA2;
int p1  = 0x00;
int p2  = 0x00;
//int LC  = 0x08;'
byte[] data = new byte[] {(byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0x08};
int le  = 0x0D;

ResponseAPDU respApdu = channel.transmit(
                             new CommandAPDU(cla, ins, p1, p2, data, le));
```

**Case 2:** (Encouraged)

```
byte[] apdu = new byte[] {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA2, (byte) 0x00, (byte)
              0x00, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x0D};

ResponseAPDU respApdu = channel.transmit(
                             new CommandAPDU(apdu));
```

Read more about [CommandAPDU](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CommandAPDU.html) and [CardChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardChannel.html#transmit-javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU-).

**Case 3:** (Mostly used way)

```
String apdu = "00A2000002EF080D"; //also u can append strings into apdu
ResponseAPDU respApdu = channel.transmit(
                             new CommandAPDU(toByteArray(apdu)));
```

You need a *Helper* function:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
}
```

**Attention:** The example APDU values you showed, `LC  '08'` means the data will be 8 bytes long, but your data field is only 2 bytes long. So check `LC` again.

Comment: thanks rakeb.void This is the actual command that am sending I want to select File and am getting this error "6A 82" which means File not found, this is the command I want to send to select file int cla = 0x00;
int ins = 0xA4;
int p1  = 0x04;
int p2  = 0x00;
byte[] data = new byte[] {(byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0x08};
int le  = 0x00;    how can I select the file using above command?

Comment: To select any file in an Applet, first you have to select that Applet by AID. So before selecting file `EF08`, did you select your Applet first? However, if file `EF08` doesn't exist in your Applet, you will definitely get an error code `6A82`.

Comment: rakeb.void yes have selected Applet AID what should I do after that using above instructions to select file Kindly assist I need to learn java card

Comment: Are you selecting ISD Applet or other Applet (payment Applet, or anything you developed)? Does that selected Applet has any file with FID `EF08`? Please read the doc came with that Applet about its File structure.

Comment: Yes the applet has EFO8 but I dont know how to go about it